# Gridview not binding with datatable after empty template

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, data-binding

When i insert any data through empty template of GridView .. values are inserted in the DB
but Gridview is not binding(done programmatically) with those values after insertion thus becomes empty i.e. not showing inserted values.

*here i am inserting only one value (in ques field of dbms table) for keeping the code short.*

**GridView HTML markup code**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" Height="146px" style="margin-top: 5px" Width="866px" >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="qno">
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="qno" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ques">
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ques" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="78px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="op1">
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="op1" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="76px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="op2">
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Top2" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="74px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="op3">
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="op3" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="74px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="op4">
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="op4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ans">
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ans" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="marks">
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="marks" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UploadImage">
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="imageP" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="save" Width="78px" OnClick="Button2_Click1" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>


                 <EmptyDataTemplate>
    <tr style="background-color: Green;">
        <th scope="col">
            qno
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            ques
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            op1
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            op2
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            op3
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            op4
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            ans
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            marks
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            imageP
        </th>
        <th scope="col">

        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="qno" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="68px" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="ques" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="68px" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="op1" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="68px" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="op2" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="68px" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="op3" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="68px" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="op4" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="68px" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="ans" runat="server"  Height="16px" Width="68px"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="marks" runat="server"  Height="16px" Width="68px"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="imageP" runat="server"  Height="16px" Width="68px"/>
        </td>

        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="Button2_Click1" CommandName = "EmptyDataTemplate" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</EmptyDataTemplate>

            </asp:GridView>
```

**C# code:**

```
public partial class qpaper : System.Web.UI.Page
{
String conStr = "Data Source=temporary; Initial Catalog=temporary1;Integrated Security=True";
String qpname = null;


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        this.BindData();
    }
}





private void BindData()
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
    {
        string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM dbms";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}




protected void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e) // save button in gridview/empty template
{

    Control control = null;
    if (GridView1.FooterRow != null)
    {
        control = GridView1.FooterRow;
    }
    else
    {
        control = GridView1.Controls[0].Controls[0];
    }
    string ques = (control.FindControl("ques") as TextBox).Text;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into dbms (ques) VALUES (@ques)"; //inserting only one value here for shortening code length
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ques", ques);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);

}
```

}

**Table structure:**

```
qno int , ques nvarchar(500), op1 nvarchar(50), op2 nvarchar(50), op3 nvarchar(50), op4 nvarchar(50), ans nvarchar(50), marks int, imagePath nvarchar(200)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have at least one column that is a **BoundField** for the auto-bind to work.

For example: This will not work

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox Id="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This will work

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="id" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox Id="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Thanks got it fixed now!